# Is lauryl glucoside stable in low pH?

Tags: organic-chemistry, ph, surfactants

I wish to use lauryl glucoside in the solution of citric acid. I tried to add it to 5% w/w solution of citric acid in water but after about 24h in the concoction which was previously clear I observed a kind of sediment. It looked like a "white smoke" disspersed in the clear liquid. I wonder whether it can be the effect of hydrolysis of glucoside due to the low pH (about 2) of the solution...

I used:

- distilled water,
- clear citric acid,
- clear lauryl glucoside.

Can someone provide an information in what pH values lauryl glucoside is stable? Do you know how to explain what happened with my solution?

Comment: I have no specific knowledge of lauryl glucoside, but the key feature of the molecule (where the lauryl alcohol joins the glucose molecule) is an acetal and they are certainly hydrolysed in aqueous acid of pH1 or stronger. pH2 for an extended time seems likely to produce a slow hydrolysis.

Comment: Thank you for this response @Waylander. I suspect the white sediment to be a dodecanol then... It's interesting because I know some bathroom cleaners that consist of aquenous solution of citric acid, lauryl glucoside and decyl glucoside and the pH is 2,4 - 3,0

Comment: Remember pH is a log scale, pH2 is ten times as concentrated at pH3. So the difference between 2.0 and 2.4 is a lot of H+ ions. Acetals are considered stable in the pH2-4 range so I suspect you are just over the edge of stability with your solution

Comment: Fair point. I'll try to prepare solutions with higher pH and see how it works. Thanks! :)